How to stop VS Code from creating default build task on F5 press?
By accident I selected "don't ask me again" on some feature in VS Code after pressing F5. Now, every time I press F5, it adds the default task in the tasks.json even when I have two other tasks in there. How do I make it stop doing that or ask me which build task to run when I press F5? Here is the before and after tasks.json.
Before:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "C/C++: g++-13: Debug, x64",
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "g++ build: Debug x64",
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-O0",
                "-m64",
                "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}/main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/${workspaceFolderBasename}.out",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/include/mavsdk",
                "-L${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "C/C++: g++-13: Release, x64",
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "g++ build: Release x64",
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-O3",
                "-m64",
                "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}/main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/${workspaceFolderBasename}.out",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/include/mavsdk",
                "-L${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

After:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "C/C++: g++-13: Debug, x64",
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "g++ build: Debug x64",
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-O0",
                "-m64",
                "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}/main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/${workspaceFolderBasename}.out",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/include/mavsdk",
                "-L${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "C/C++: g++-13: Release, x64",
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "g++ build: Release x64",
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-O3",
                "-m64",
                "${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}/main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/${workspaceFolderBasename}.out",
                "-I${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/include/mavsdk",
                "-L${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/MAVSDK/lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-13 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}


I found the issue to be the "label". I renamed "label" to be "C/C++: g++-13 build active file" in my two tasks and it stopped generating the third default task. I don't know why, but VS Code searches for tasks with label ""C/C++: g++-13 build active file". If it does not find it, it generates a new one and runs that one.

Either remove the "isDefault": true line or set it to 'false' or delete the entire task if you don't need it anymore.

Every time I press F5, it generates the default tasks and set it to default no matter what I do.
